# Printing XLS file programmatically without Excel installed

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, visual-studio

I have a VB6 application that produces and prints .xls files thanks to an old and deprecated component. It isn't compatible with some of the new printers drivers (makes my application freeze and crash when a print occurs) , so I would like to find an alternative knowing that most PC where my application runs don't have Office installed.

I can't install "big" packages so I'm limited to the already-installed framework .Net 3.5. I can install pdfcreator or ExcelViewer though.

I'm looking for the cleanest way to implement it. I won't find anything native in VB6 so I'll just make an external call to something I've coded, so the technology used doesn't really matter.

I found only one solution for now and I consider it dirty : with an autoit script, I open Excelviewer and order it to print with autoit then close the file. It works but I'd like to find something more silent/user-friendly. I tried VBS but it is not supported by ExcelViewer. I found a .net 4.0 assembly GemBox but it's .net 4.0 (and expensive). I didn't manage to make my excel file a pdf to print the pdf with pdfcreator.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: *I can't install "big" packages* What does that mean?

Comment: Well, over 50 Mo is already too big of an update. We have like 100 distant servers to maintain and we have a bad upload bandwidth. It would take ages and make us unable to work effectively because it would affect our download bandwidth.

Comment: If your application is producing the .xls files, couldn't it also just produce csv or txt?